# javascript replace last occurrence of string

Tags: regex, replace

I've read many Q&As in StackOverflow and I'm still having a hard time getting RegEX.
I have string `12_13_12`.

How can I replace last occurrence of 12 with, `aa`.

Final result should be `12_13_aa`.

I would really like for good explanation about how you did it.

Comment: will that last number always contain 2 digits?

Comment: @GintasK no.. it wont always contain 2 digits and so as the other pair of numbers

Comment: '12_13_12'.replace(/12([^1][^2])*$/, 'aa') // 12 followed by any not 12 pattern

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
newString = oldString.substring(0,oldString.lastIndexOf("_")) + 'aa';
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use this replace:

```
var str = '12-44-12-1564';
str = str.replace(/12(?![\s\S]*12)/, 'aa');
console.log(str);
```

explanations:

```
(?!            # open a negative lookahead (means not followed by)
   [\s\S]*     # all characters including newlines (space+not space)
               # zero or more times
   12
)              # close the lookahead
```

In other words the pattern means: *12 not followed by another 12 until the end of the string.*

Comment: +1 for using a regex solution and adding a detailed explanation.

Comment: (plus one) for not requiring the search string to be at the end ($)

Answer (score 3):

Use this `String.replace` and make sure you have end of input `$` in the end:

```
repl = "12_13_12".replace(/12(?!.*?12)/, 'aa');
```

**EDIT:** To use a variable in Regex:

```
var re = new RegExp(ToBeReplaced);
repl = str.replace(re, 'aa');
```

Comment: it was just an example

Comment: actually, if i got it right, the $ means for last occurrence of the number/string 12, right? cause it is so, it suppose to work.

Comment: and when i use it in replace method the entire regex expression not suppose to be as a string , right? cause i have something like something.replace (/ + ToBeReplaced + $/, replaceValue)

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution, and it does satisfy the sample text however this assumes the string `12` will be at the end of the string, which is different then the last occurrence of the `12`.

Comment: @Denomales: Fair point mate, I edited my answer to take care of this.

Comment: @redV: `"12_13_12".replace(/12(?!.*?12)/, 'aa');` gives `12_13_aa` replacing **last** `12` by `aa`

Comment: @anubhava I mean to say the second example you gave with `toBeReplaced`. Is that an example for dynamic Regex building or as an answer to OP's question?

Comment: @redV: You can clearly see from edit that section was added later to respond to a question asked by OP in comments which was **and when i use it in replace method the entire regex expression not suppose to be as a string , right? cause i have something like something.replace (/ + ToBeReplaced + $/, replaceValue)**

Comment: @anubhava Ok I understood. It was confusing because you took two examples each one with different purpose. +1 from me.